# Approach handling data that are introduced “Bottom-up” and refined “Top-down”

Tags: strategy-pattern, bottom-up, top-down

(This question is about *strategy* and *high-level approach to data refining*, not *programming*, so if it is off-topic... sorry in advance, but I couldn't find a better stackexchange community)

So, we are in a (typical) scenario in which new data are introduced by a moltitude of users (*bottom-up* contribution) and periodically refined, corrected, categorized and enriched by moderators/administrators/trusted users (*top-down* refining).

This scenario is quite common in websites (stackexchange `tags` are a good example)

Is there a "best strategy" to minimize efforts and maximize the quality of data?

Here some doubt:

1. Force data to pass a validation process or let them populate the system (accepting a certain grade of incorrectness/inconsistency) and fix/enrich the most popular as they arise.
2. Top-down-prefill the system with as much data as you can anticipating the bottom-up arrivals.
3. Help bottom-up entries to be consistent with the rest of other data (autocompletes and did-you-mean boxes for the user)